# Trying to throttle just for the jump keypress Javascript HTML5 Canvas Game

Tags: javascript, canvas, throttling

Still new at this, have been searching and searching. I see some answers but the code looks a bit different from mine using var and a few others. I found this code to use.

```
function throttle(cb, delay = 2000) {
  let shouldWait = false

  return (...args) => {
    if (shouldWait) return

    cb (...args)
    shouldWait = true

    setTimeout(() => {
      shouldWait = false
    }, delay)
  }
}
```

To my understanding that part is correct. I have the basic movement keys. I only want to throttle the jump keypress. Case 87: any help would be greatly appreciated. Trying to avoid players tapping the jump button to fly everywhere. I've tried other alternatives but throttling would solve my problem.

```
addEventListener('keydown', ({ keyCode }) => {
  if (game.disableUserInput) return
  var lastEnter = null;

  switch (keyCode) {
    case 65:
      console.log('left')
      keys.left.pressed = true
      lastKey = 'left'

      break

    case 83:
      console.log('down')
      break

    case 68:
      console.log('right')
      keys.right.pressed = true
      lastKey = 'right'

      break

    case 87: // W
      console.log('up')    
      if (event.repeat) { return }
      player.velocity.y -= 25           

      break
```

Comment: Here's a far better approach: [Move player using keyboard in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72250837/383904). Actually it makes it almost a duplicate. Regarding the **jump**: you just need to add a `player.isJump = true;` when "W" key is pressed, and set it back to `false` when: both `player.isJump` is `true` ***and***  you detect a collision with the ground.

Comment: Originally that's what I was looking for. Just couldn't seem to make it work. Spent countless hours trying to figure this out, I've learned a lot just not how to solve this problem.

Comment: Having issues with trying all the player.isJump alternatives. If I can basically disable the jump button for 2-3 seconds after being pressed once it would solve my problem.